# Jquery panel slider won't close after I changed its CSS from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295133/jquery-panel-slider-opens-with-button-click-but-wont-close) question.

I have fixed the jquery. Now I want to use it from the left side instead of right. So I changed its class from "cd-panel from-right" to "cd-panel from left". It works well while opening but The button is disabled after it opens and cannot be closed.

I tried to tweak things in CSS such as changing "left"s to "right" and vice versa but had no luck. On JSfiddle CSS nothing is changed but the button's position.

HTML:

```
<div class="cd-panel from-left">
    <div class="cd-panel-container">
    <button href="#0" class="cd-btn btn-primary">Views</button>
    <div class="cd-panel-content" ng-controller="ViewtreeCtrl">

    </div>
    <!-- cd-panel-content -->
</div>
<!-- cd-panel-container -->
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open the lateral panel
    $('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhz00zas/1/) (You can see the CSS on JSFiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is not being disabled, but it's displayed under the `.cd-panel-content` div.

To solve this, you can add `z-index:1` to `.cd-btn` class.

Another solution might be to add `pointer-events:none` to `.cd-panel-content`, but in that case, links on `.cd-panel-content` won't work, so I'll go with `z-index` solution.